# how to handle expressJs callback and how to update object's property inside a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, callback

I have two js files. i am able to get data from mongodb by calliing bookDao.getActiveBookByCategoryId().

**My Problem**

In categoryDao.js file i am trying to update  `resultJson.book_count`inside `BookDao.getActiveBookByCategoryId()` method. but it is not updating. So may i know how to fix this.
here `book_count` property in `resultJson`  is still 0.

**categoryDao.js**

```
module.exports.getAllActiveCategory = (callback) => {
    Category.find({
        is_delete : false
    }, (error, result) => {
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
            callback(commonUtil.ERROR);
        }

        if(result) {
            var categoryArray = [];
            for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++) {
                var categorySingle = result[i];
                var resultJson = {
                    _id : categorySingle._id,
                    category_name : categorySingle.category_name,
                    created_on : categorySingle.created_on,
                    book_count : 0
                }

                BookDao.getActiveBookByCategoryId(categorySingle._id, (bookResult) => {
                    if(bookResult) {
                        if(bookResult.length > 0) {    
                            resultJson.book_count = bookResult.length;
                        }
                    }
                });
                categoryArray.push(resultJson);
            }
            callback(categoryArray);
        }
    });
}
```

**bookDao.js**

```
module.exports.getActiveBookByCategoryId = (categoryId, callback) => {
    Book.find({
        is_delete : false,
        category : categoryId
    }, (error, result) => {
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
            callback(commonUtil.ERROR);
        }

        if(result) {
            callback(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: `resultJson.book_count` is being set, but it's being set AFTER you attempt to use the JSON.  It's a timing issue.  You will have to call your completion callback only after all the calls to `BookDao.getActiveBookByCategoryId()` are done and you're thus done updating the data.  This whole thing would be a whole lot easier to manage by using promises, not plain callbacks and by using the promise interface to your database.  Then, you could use `Promise.all()` to know when all the async operations in your `for` loop were all done.

Comment: See I sorted out your one issue for how to handle callbacks. You can review this codesandbox snippet - https://codesandbox.io/s/k7p523453

Comment: @MeetZaveri tried your code. but it's not working

Comment: @jfriend00 may i know how to use Promise.All() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, In your code `categoryArray.push(resultJson);` will not wait for `BookDao.getActiveBookByCategoryId` to finish because of async behavior.

```
module.exports.getActiveBookByCategoryId = (categoryId) => {
    return Book.count({
        is_delete: false,
        category: categoryId
    });
}


module.exports.getAllActiveCategory = async () => {
    try {
        // Find all category
        const result = await Category.find({
            is_delete: false
        });

        // Create array of promise
        const promises = result.map(categorySingle => BookDao.getActiveBookByCategoryId(categorySingle._id));
        // Get array of Category count
        const data = await Promise.all(promises);
        // update count in result
        return result.map((categorySingle, i) => {
            categorySingle.book_count = data[i];
            return categorySingle;
        });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}
```

Comment: can you please explain how promises is working here ?